# Angular: Styles from primeng not working even they are listed in styles.scss

Tags: css, angular, styles, primeng

I have added primeng to my Angular project. But the styles don't work.

I have put the styles in style.scss and in angular.json. but always i do ng serve it doesn't work

My styles.scss:

```
@import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css';
@import '../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css';
@import '../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
```

My complete angular.json:
I have to give some more details to the code to save it so I do it here.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "gw-spc": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/gw-spc",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "gw-spc:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "gw-spc:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "gw-spc:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "gw-spc:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "gw-spc:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My login.component.html:

```
<h3 class="p-text-center p-pt-2" >Anmelden</h3>
<hr>
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="anmelden_click()" class="ui-fluid m-3">
  <div class="ui-fluid">
    <div class="p-field">
      <label for="benutzer">Benutzername:</label>
      <p-autoComplete formControlName="benutzer" id="benutzer" [suggestions]="filteredUser"
        (completeMethod)="search($event)" [emptyMessage]="'Kein Benutzer!'"
        [required]="true"></p-autoComplete>
    </div>
    <div class="p-field">
      <label for="passwort">Passwort/PIN:</label>
      <input formControlName="passwort" id="passwort" type="password" pPassword [feedback]="false">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label class="schrift-kleiner schrift-rot" controlName="fehler"></label>
    </div>
    <!--div class="p-field">
      <label for="werk">Werk:</label>
      <p-dropdown formControlName="werk" [options]="werke" [(ngModel)]="selectedWerk" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label class="schrift-kleiner schrift-rot" controlName="fehlerWerk"></label>
    </div-->
  </div>
  <div class="p-formgroup-inline p-jc-center">
    <p-button styleClass="ui-button-success" label="anmelden"></p-button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The site I get:

[image]

Why doesn't it work what do I wrong please help.

The Index.html:
[image]

[image]

Comment: which version of angular primng you use ?..FYI if you change somethings in angular.json you should kill terminal and restart project ...you did it ?

Comment: @SouhailChougrani angular version 15.1.4 primeng version 15.2.0. what you mean with kill the terminal and restart project? I did new ng serve

Comment: Now I restarted everything. Even my pc. It does not work...

Comment: I create a project with primeng and a got the same result as you...first there is no doubt that primeng theming was applicated as we can see in button style...now i think what you need is the help classes that come with primeng liks "m-1" "p-2" ...etc you should add install  primeflex  "npm install primeflex"  and add it in sytles : []

Comment: @SouhailChougrani please see in my angular.json that primeflex is already installed and added in styles : [] So I think this is not the soultion. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @SouhailChougrani I think I have the solution. I 've used old keywords as css classes. there are new keywords. That's all

Comment: @SouhailChougrani The styles do not work after all. There is something else missing. someone else who can help?

Comment: Can you provide an example in stackblitz?

Comment: You should try changing the order in which styles are listed in your angular.json file (styles.scss at the bottom).

Comment: @BibekKhadka Thank you for your answer. unfortunately this doesn't work either

Comment: Could you inspect the page in browser and see which styles are being applied and in which order? Also include that in your question.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show the 'Styles' tab. Inspect the particular element which you think is missing the css from primeng for example maybe the login button and check the 'Styles' tab to see which css styling is being applied and from which css file.

Comment: As you can see the issue isn't that primeng styles aren't applied. They are definitely configured and being applied. I don't see any styles from your styles.scss file and that's what you need to look into.

Comment: @BibekKhadka Thank you. What does it mean you don't see styles from styles.scss. what do I have to do now?

Comment: I suggest that you create a different scss file and serve it from the assets folder. Link the file in the index.html file as you'd do in any html css project.

Comment: Honestly, for someone to be able to help you correctly, you should create an example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/). There's too much going on and any file / configuration could be the cause of this issue. If you can reproduce it on stackblitz and show us the code on stackblitz, someone might be able to provide you with a correct solution. Too much information is missing.

Comment: Try to remove "defaultConfiguration": "" in angular.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered this problem in the past fairly often.

The only thing that worked for me, was to use a different primeng version in my project. Try to play around with different versions, it will work for one of them.

Comment: Hope this won't be the only solution. This would make much effort because the project is nearly done so everything changing to a old version would be worse :-(

Comment: PrimeNG version 15.2.0 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The solution was add "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" and "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css" to the "styles" section founded in the angular.json file (root folder)

```
`  
      "styles": [
          "src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss", 
          "src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
          "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"]
`
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are including bootstrap.css in your project, there is a clash between primeng and bootstrap in the newer versions.

Comment: You might want to elaborate, especially on how to solve.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is actually a misleading - in order to save some time from future readers, I'm successfully using bootstrap along side primeng bootstrap versions. These are my imported styles:

            "styles": [
              "src/custom-theme.scss",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/bootstrap.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap4-light-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
            ],